# Is it possible to return an array in a VBA function?

Tags: vba

I hope this isn't a repeat (I looked all over and couldn't find a straight answer - I'm probably missing something obvious).

If it's possible, how is it done? I'm not trying to output to any cells.

Comment: array of string? array of integer?

Comment: Does it make a difference? I'm asking generally.

Comment: Are you asking how to do arrays in VBA? There are a bunch of sites detailing how to do it. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) is one and [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html) is another.  Or am I not understanding your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Just put parentheses after the return type in the function.

Here is a simple example function and sub using it:

```
 Sub test3()
      Dim myarray() As String
      myarray = returnarray()
      MsgBox myarray(2)
 End Sub

 Function returnarray() As String()

      returnarray = Split("test1, test2, test3", ",")

 End Function
```